# Android Java: Binarize and Process an image

Tags: java, android

After decoding an image this way Iam passing it to a read file

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 5, 5, bitmap.getWidth() - 10, bitmap.getHeight() - 10,matrix,true);
       System.out.println("The new cropped bitmap>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + croppedBitmap.getWidth() + "<<<>>>>" +croppedBitmap.getHeight());
       this.bmp = croppedBitmap;
Readfile.readBitmap(bitmap)
```

Now I am processing and binarizing an image this way.

```
Pix var2 = Binarize.otsuAdaptiveThreshold(var1);
      var2 = Rotate.rotate(AdaptiveMap.backgroundNormMorph(Convert.convertTo8(var1), 8, 6, 250), Skew.findSkew(var2));
```

The above algorithm does a good job on the background service and produces the result but my present challenge is that it takes such a long time (40 seconds) to process the image. So my intention is to process and binarize the image at 10 seconds that made me arrive by the approach above, so am asking is there a way I can decrease the processing time to about 10 seconds.
Thanks!

Comment: Skew detection is a very slow process. You could reduce the quality of the skew detection or use a smaller image. There may also be implementations of otsu or background normalization that can take advantage of GPU acceleration, but I never got around to implementing that in tesseract-android-tools.